# Storing Smtp from email friendly display name in Web.Config

Tags: .net, smtp, web-config

I'm storing my mailsettings in the web config like so...

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="splidge@findremovalcompanies.com">
        <network host="smtp.findremovalcompanies.com" userName="splidge@findremovalcompanies.com" password="password" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Now when I create a new

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
```

smpt has my credentials and will default the from address to splidge@findremovalcompanies.com which saves me from having to do this every time.

```
MailAddress("splidge@findremovalcompanies.com", "Splidge Master")
```

But I cannot figure out how to specify the friendly display name "Splidge Master" in the web.config theres no setting for it?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You can use html encoded < and > (&lt; and &gt;) to deliver a display name in the from attribute.

`<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Mail Displayname &lt;mail@raccoom.net&gt;">`

Comment: Got it a few seconds before me :-)

Comment: For the first time I was faster... before while I was typing my answer the other answers were posted ,)

Comment: I use System.Web.Helpers.WebMail. I wonder why the display name appears if I set it through WebMail.From, but it doesn't if I set it through Web.config.

Answer (score 14):

From memory, changing the `from=` attribute to be `from="Display Name &lt;me@example.com&gt;"` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exact equivalent, encode the double quotes (`&quot;`) too :

```
<smtp from="&quot;Splidge Master&quot; &lt;splidge@findremovalcompanies.com&gt;">
```