# Is there a way to include an email address "display name" in the smtp element of a Web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing Smtp from email friendly display name in Web.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394354/storing-smtp-from-email-friendly-display-name-in-web-config)

I'm working on an `EmailSender`, and I'm grabbing the email address from my Web.config file. I'd like to also grab a "display name" for that email, from the same section if possible, but I'm not seeing an obvious way to do this.

In my Web.config file, I have included a default "from email address", like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="myaddress@mydomain.com"><!-- no displayName attribute :( -->
        <network ... />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

In my `EmailSender`, I have something like this:

```
        var smtpSection = ...;
        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.From =  new MailAddress(_settings.From, senderDisplayName);
```

**Is there a recommended way to store `senderDisplayName` in a web.config file?**

- Is there some way to include it in the `from` attribute? For example:

  ```
  <smtp from="Automatic Mailer &lt;myaddress@mydomain.com&gt;">
  ```
- Or does it need to be a custom element in `appSettings`?
- Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here check this thread, might be of help:

[Storing Smtp from email friendly display name in Web.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394354/storing-smtp-from-email-friendly-display-name-in-web-config)

Comment: Good answer.  +1 for finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you HAVE to pull the email address etc from the web.config? Why not set it in the EmailSender?

> The MailAddress constructor also includes an overload that allows the display name to be specified (New MailAddress(address, displayName). Most email clients display the display name, if present, instead of the email address.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150649/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101707-1.aspx

Comment: I would prefer it in Web.config because the information might change (e.g., people might think they're receiving spam with the current name--might need to try other ideas). Bottom line: I might need to change the info after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I set it in the Web.Config in the AppSettings section, since the smtp settings section doesn't provide a place for it.