# Email: How to show only Display name for the From Address?

Tags: c#, email

I am writing a C# tool which send out email report. While sending the email report,I configure From and To address.

To address is automatically resolved to outlook Display name when delivered.

However, From address does not resolve it. On analyzing across the board,I come across this thread.
[Storing Smtp from email friendly display name in Web.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394354/storing-smtp-from-email-friendly-display-name-in-web-config)

This displays the mail address as
**My Name <MyName@MyCompany.com>**

However, I Just want to see only  **My Name** similar to a mail when I send it from outlook.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Smtp from email friendly display name in Web.Config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394354/storing-smtp-from-email-friendly-display-name-in-web-config)

Comment: No,  I mentioned that link already in my question.My question is different. All I want is "From" address should be resolved like "To" address

Comment: @karpanai : Maybe the way it gets displayed depends on the email viewer (and outlook shows it differently than gmail/yahoo/...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify display names while instantiating MailAddress class.
ex. MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com", "Ben Miller"); Check below URL for sample code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.displayname.aspx

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It's exactly same as the one I mentioned in the above link. I tried this as well

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what code you use now... Anyway, if you [automate Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) you need to use the [Recipients.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipients.add.aspx) method for adding recipients (To, Cc or Bcc) and then call the [Resolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipient.resolve.aspx) or [ResolveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipients.resolveall.aspx) methods.

```
private void SetRecipientTypeForMail()
{
    Outlook.MailItem mail = Application.CreateItem(
      Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.Subject = "Sample Message";
    Outlook.Recipient recipTo =
      mail.Recipients.Add("someone@example.com");
    recipTo.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
    Outlook.Recipient recipCc =
      mail.Recipients.Add("someonecc@example.com");
    recipCc.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
    Outlook.Recipient recipBcc =
      mail.Recipients.Add("someonebcc@example.com");
    recipBcc.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
    mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
    mail.Display(false);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is again for resolving "To" address.. I am wondering whether is there any way to resolve "From" address

Comment: It doesn't matter where it should be used - from or to. You need to created a recipient object and use the resolve method. `Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Dan Wilson") `
 
 `myRecipient.Resolve`

Comment: hi, I am using MailMessage class, as described in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449887/sending-e-mail-using-c-sharp. How do I convert "outlook recipient" to "from address" of MailMessage

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide such class. It seems the question is not related to Outlook.

Comment: I removed the Outlook tag from the question.